# Custom button corners in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I need to create this button in my project. The problem is how to make these different style corners. Can i do this by xml or maybe there is an already-existing library?[image: small buttonbig one]

I have already tried just importing it as svg, but all these buttons are different in their size, and i have a lot of files in my project. So i need to write one xml shape with custom corners or import some external lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ShapeAppearanceModel` from  Material Components Library provides helper functions to build each corner specifically. You can use the `CornerFamily.CUT` to build a cut corner and the `CornerFamily.ROUNDED` to build a rounded corner.

**1.Example for Material Components like `MaterialButton`, `MaterialCardView` etc. which they already have a ShapeAppearanceModel by default:**

**Xml:**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
  android:id="@+id/materialButton"
  android:layout_width="150dp"
  android:layout_height="60dp"
  android:text="Next"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  app:backgroundTint="#1BE951"/>
```

**Usage:**

```
val cutRadius = dpsToPixels(15f, this)
val roundedRadius = dpsToPixels(15f, this)

val materialButton = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.materialButton)
materialButton.shapeAppearanceModel = materialButton.shapeAppearanceModel
    .toBuilder()
    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, cutRadius)
    .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, cutRadius)
    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, roundedRadius)
    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, roundedRadius)
    .build()
```

with a helper function to convert the dps to pixels:

```
fun dpsToPixels(dp: Float, context: Context): Float {
    return dp * (context.resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
}
```

**2.Example for Non Material Components like `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc. which they don't have a ShapeAppearanceModel:**

**Xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

**Usage:**

```
val cutRadius = dpsToPixels(15f, this)
val roundedRadius = dpsToPixels(15f, this)

val relativeLayout = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.relativeLayout)
val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setTopRightCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, cutRadius)
    .setBottomLeftCorner(CornerFamily.CUT, cutRadius)
    .setTopLeftCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, roundedRadius)
    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, roundedRadius)
    .build()
val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
shapeDrawable.fillColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light);
ViewCompat.setBackground(relativeLayout, shapeDrawable)
```

**Result:**

[image: Button_Corners]

Answer (score 0):

you won't achieve this with XML only, bu you can and should use graphic in 9-patch format. take a look on [official DOC](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch). you may create one white shape and colorize it with button tint or any other dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this somewhat style by creating a custombutton xml in your drawable folder. Then you just have to work on the radius numbers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid 
android:color="#eeffffff" />
  <corners 
   android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
  </shape>
```

Then just reference the xml in the button

Comment: I do this with all my buttons and backgrounds. The radius for the flat portion of the button I think is around 150